# Java Classes parametrized by integers: Is it possible/what's the best way to approximate it?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, interface

Here is a class that represents a Sha-1 hash. It has a length constant so that it can perform validation of hex strings in its static factory method.

```
class Sha1Hash {
    private static final hexStringLength = 40;
    Pattern hexStringPattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9a-f]{" + hexStringLength + "}$");

    // constructor 

    static Sha1Hash fromHexString(String hexString) throws Exception {
        if(!hexStringPattern.matches(hexString)) {
            // throw an error
        }
        // otherwise, return a Sha1Hash object
    }

    // various other static factory methods and instance methods
}
```

I want to make a md5 hash object which will have hex strings of length 32. It will share all the same methods as the Sha1Hash including the factory methods. My initial idea was to do something like this:

```
abstract class Hash<N extends Size> {
    private final hexStringLength = N.getValue();
    Pattern hexStringPattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9a-f]{" + hexStringLength + "}$");
    // implement methods, not sure how to implement static factory methods
}

class Sha1Hash extends Hash<SizeForty> {}
class Md5Hash extends Hash<SizeThirtyTwo> {}
```

Here, `Size` has a static method `getValue` that should just return an integer. However, this doesn't seem to be possible. Is there an alternative? I also don't know if there is a way to avoid deduplicating the static factory methods for each class.

Comment: You may want to look into using an existing library for hashing. Apache Commons-Codec has a [DigestUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) class. Guava has a [Hashing](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html) class. Better to use those than to reinvent the wheel. You can also look at the source code for those libraries to see how the authors organized the code that is common between the different hashing algorithms.

Comment: You are focusing too much on the “easier one” of the impossible things. How is a static factory method in class `Hash` supposed to know whether it shall return `Sha1Hash` or `Md5Hash`? In fact, if there was a way to solve that problem, the other became solvable, e.g. via annotations or reflection. But as long as the factory method doesn’t know what to produce, it doesn’t matter much that is also doesn’t know the valid string length.